# Why is my print statement after my for loop not printing?

Tags: java

I'm a first year compsci major and I can't figure out how to solve this programming assignment. The specific problem is that I'm unable to create a new line at the end of the output. I've been able to figure out how to create new lines in between the integers, but I need to have a new line only after the last one.

Here's the instructions:

> Read integer numVals from input as the number of integers to be read next. Use a loop to read the remaining integers from input. Output all integers on the same line, and surround each integer with angle brackets. Lastly, end with a newline.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> 2
> 95 60
> then the output is:
>
> <95><60>

And the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AngleBrackets {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numVals;

      int i;
      numVals = scnr.nextInt();
      for(i = -100; i <= numVals; i++) {
         numVals = scnr.nextInt();
         System.out.print("<" + numVals + ">");
      }
      System.out.println();

   }
}
```

I have tried to put the code within the loop, but that makes it print a new line after every integer. I have also tried putting the print after the for loop however it is not printing. I also looked up similar codes on here, but they do not exactly give me the answer that I am looking for.

Comment: Hint: you should read all the inputs, *then* write the outputs.

Comment: You should also check your loop condition... currently, with your input of "2" you're actually going to ask for 103 numbers...

Comment: are you sure, that the line feed is not being printed. How did you check just that?

Comment: Why is `i = -100` ?

Comment: Also, within the loop, do not use your variable `numVals` to store the next int from the Scanner. Store the integers in another variable because in your solution the next read integer might stop the loop depending on its value. That's probably also why you decided to start the loop at -100.

Answer (score 2):

I will sum up what was said in the comments :

- The start of the loop should be i = 0;
- numVals should not be overwritten as it is the condition to exit your loop, if you want to store the value of scnr.nextInt() you should create a new variable. Also if one of the number read is -500 for example it will loop forever.
- Finally to check if the new line is correctly print you can print something else after the System.out.println() (Don't forget to remove it after)

Here is what the code should look like :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AngleBrackets {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numVals;

      numVals = scnr.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i <= numVals; i++) {
         int newVal = scnr.nextInt();
         System.out.print("<" + newVal + ">");
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Is this a new line ?");
   }
}
```

You can also replace

```
int newVal = scnr.nextInt();
System.out.print("<" + newVal + ">");
```

by

```
System.out.print("<" + scnr.nextInt() + ">");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-assigning *numVals* within the *for-loop*.

Instead, just print the value.

```java
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int numVals;

numVals = scnr.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < numVals; i++)
    System.out.printf("<%d>", scnr.nextInt());
System.out.println();
```

Output

```
3
1 2 3
<1><2><3>
```